# Citrix Receiver for Windows 3.0

Tags: citrix

I've had a solid PresentationServer 4.0 working for 4 years. This new receiver is causing massive issues.

I am getting this error on multiple machines now.

> The network connection to your application was interrupted. Try to
>   access your application later, or contact your help desk

The "Tw2CachePower" registry edit does not work.

> Event ID 1 (ICA Client [Vanadium]) in Application Events

Anyone have answers to correct the issue beside the non-working solution from Citrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're having the same issue. In testing I found that setting SSPIEnabled = Off in the wfclient.ini as [described here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX115648) helped. However I still get the error if I try to launch the Application again without logging off/on.

I haven't left the setting as off as I'm not sure of the security implications; the setting relates to kerberos security. Are the any Citrix security experts could clarify that?

Comment: Chris thanks for the input, I will give a look at this. I did noticed in the release notes that PS4 is not supported officially as far as I can tell. Seems like a pretty important fact to just blow over. I'm not privy to the affect on security, would also like to know.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to go about doing this.

### Deleting the license key.

1. Launch regedit.
2. Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing
3. Right-click MSLicensing, and then click Delete.
4. Click on "Yes" to confirm deletion.
5. Quit Registry Editor.

### Exported Registration File

Export the mslicensing reg file from a working system and copy it to the one that isn't working. Delete the existing reg file and register with the newly copied one.

### Print Spooler Problems

Stop your "Print Spooler" service. I have had users who had some Printers that weren't connected. I deleted them, tried again, and it worked.